# Lazy match Node regex over multiple lines

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a bunch of javascript files and pull out certain objects. an example of the file would be:

```
import { foo } from "blah";
import { bar, baz } from "../module";

const myobject = {
    name: NAME,
    title: {
        name: `${NAME}.title`,
        defaultMessage: "title",
    },
    description: {
        name: `${NAME}.description`,
        defaultMessage: "description",
    },
    property: 'stringvalue',
};

const anotherObject = {
        name: `${NAME}.other`,
        defaultMessage: "other",
}
```

I need to pull out all the objects that have the property "defaultMessage". For the matcher I have:

```
/\{([\s\S]*?)defaultMessage([\s\S]*?)\}/g
```

This is matching *anotherObject* and *myobject.description* correctly, but for *myobject.title* it's getting everything from the first `{` before foo. e.g:

```
{ foo } from "blah";
import { bar, baz } from "../module";

const myobject = {
    name: NAME,
    title: {
        name: `${NAME}.title`,
        defaultMessage: "Main",
    }
```

How can I get this to lazy match further so I only get:

```
{
    name: `${NAME}.title`,
    defaultMessage: "Main",
}
```

Update: I'll be using node to parse the javascript files, so I get access to negative look behinds, I tried the following with no luck:

```
(?<!\{[\s\S]+?)\{([\s\S]+?)defaultMessage([\s\S]*?)\}
```

Comment: It is not possible to match nested brackets in Javascript regex. Use a parser instead.

Comment: But it is matching inside nested brackets, I'm getting the object at `description` fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use this in any production code but this would work for your case:

```
([a-zA-Z]*?)(?:\s=|:)\s(\{(?:(?!([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s=|:)\s\{)[\s\S])*?defaultMessage(?:[\s\S]*?)\})
```

I added `([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s=|:)\s`, so that we only capture the opening bracket if it is prefixed by `xyZ =` or `abC:'.

Also added a negative lookahead so that the pattern doesn't repeat itself:

```
(?!([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s=|:)\s\{)
```

Furthermore I added some non capturing groups in order to decrease regex group clutter if you intend to use this in some code. For example this regex captures:

```
    title: {
        name: `${NAME}.title`,
        defaultMessage: "title",
    }
```

With `title` as sub group 1

and:

```
{
        name: `${NAME}.title`,
        defaultMessage: "title",
}
```

As subgroup 2, you can approach subgroup 2 in order to get your desired capture.

Alternatively use:

```
(?=[a-zA-Z]*?)\{(?:(?!([a-zA-Z]*?)(\s=|:)\s\{)[\s\S])*?defaultMessage(?:[\s\S]*?)\}
```

To only capture:

```
{
        name: `${NAME}.title`,
        defaultMessage: "title",
}
```

With no subgroups

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Snagtz, it did reduce selecting the imports, but is now including the object key or constant. I need just the object: `{
    name: `${NAME}.title`,
    defaultMessage: "Main",
}`

Comment: @sansSpoon I see, editted my answer. I think it should work for you now.